# Reset a mat-select value by clicking a button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select dropdown for filtering data on the UI. I emit the data from the child component to the parent component with the getTeam function

**Mat-Select**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select Team</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="getTeam($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team.name">
      {{team.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<span class="material-icons" (click)="reset()">delete_sweep</span>
```

**Filter logic (.ts)**
The getTeamQuery receives the emitted value and filters the UI data.

```
  videos: Video[] = videos;
  filteredVideos: Video[] = videos;

    getTeamQuery(queryEmitted: string) {
    this.videos = this.filteredVideos.filter(video => {
      return video.team === queryEmitted;
    });
  }


  **Clearing the filter selection**

  reset() {
    this.videos = videos;
  }
```

How can I reset the selection of the mat-select and return to the initial state, by clicking the material icon? Initial state, meaning the state where the mat-select value is the placeholder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add a normal mat-option before the loop, like following:

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="getTeam($event)">
    <mat-option value="">Select a name...</mat-option>

    <mat-option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team.name">
      {{team.name}}
    </mat-option>

  </mat-select>
```

**EDIT:** as per your comment, you can use ngModel for this case, like following:

**html file:**

```
<mat-select (selectionChange)="getTeam($event)" [(ngModel)]="teamInitial">
  // your code...
</mat-select>
```

**ts file:**

```
export class YourComponent {
   teamInitial = '';

   // you code...

   reset() {
     this.teamInitial = '';
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, good idea. But the question here is, how do I reset the mat-select button on its initial state, by clicking a clear button.

Comment: i have edited the answer according to your comment, please check... @v_char

Comment: it worked, thanks. do you think the question needs edit?

Comment: Yes, you can change the title like "Reset mat-select value using button click" or something like that... and you also may edit your question, you wanted a button click event, but in your html example you don't give any button template. or you didn't say exactly how you wanted to reset. so at first glance, it was bit confusing .,

Comment: ok, thanks. I have the material icon where I attached a click function, on html

Comment: Perfect. Adding ng-model solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

```js
interface measurement {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}
export class SelectOverviewExample {
 RemoveDefaultSelectValue : any;
 
  measurements: measurement[] = [
      {value: 'LineString', viewValue: 'Line String'},
      {value: 'Polygon', viewValue: 'Area'},
  ];
}
onFunChange = function(value){
    let valv = this.value;
    this.RemoveDefaultSelectValue = valv;
    $("#stopmesrment").on('click', () =>{
      this.RemoveDefaultSelectValue = {};
    });
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Measurement</mat-label>
     <mat-select (selectionChange)="onFunChange($event)"      [value]="RemoveDefaultSelectValue" id="type" placeholder="Select Measurement" #MeasurementValue>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let measurement of measurements [value]="measurement.value">{{measurement.viewValue}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
                        
                        
<button id="stopmesrment" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">clear measurement</button>
```